# Declare variable of table type in PL/pgSQL

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I am wondering if there is a way to declare a variable of type table in PL/pgSQL to hold query results? For instance how can I express something like:

```
q1 = select * from foo;
q2 = select * from bar;
for t1 in q1:
  for t2 in q2:
    -- do something with t1 and t2
```

I looked into the return next construct but that seems to only able to handle return values.

Comment: PL/SQL => Oracle, PgPL/SQL => PostgreSQL. Which one is it you're working with?

Comment: @Mat: It's [PL/pgSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql.html), btw.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In PostgreSQL, every **table name** serves as type name for the *row type* (a.k.a. [*composite type*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html)) automatically - *not* as table type, there are no "table types" or "table variables" in Postgres ([but there are typed tables](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/116088/3684)).
So you can declare a variable of that type in [`PL/pgSQL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html).

```
CREATE FUNCTION foo()
  RETURNS void
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   q1 foo;  -- "foo" ...
   q2 bar;  -- ... and "bar" are existing (visible) table names
BEGIN
   FOR q1 IN 
      SELECT * FROM foo
   LOOP
      FOR q2 IN 
         SELECT * FROM bar
      LOOP
         -- do something with q1 and q2
         -- you can access columns with attribute notation like: q1.col1
      END LOOP;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$
```

You could also just declare variables of the generic type [**`record`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-RECORDS). It takes any row type at assignment automatically. But special rules apply. Be sure to follow the link and read the chapter of the manual!

A `FOR` loop works with a built-in cursor. There are also explicit [cursors](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-cursors.html) in PL/pgSQL.

While it's often convenient to have the function return `SETOF <table name>`, returning `SETOF record` is not as convenient. The system does not know what the function returns this way and you have to add a column definition list with every call. Which is a pain. Details about [**table functions** in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS).

Often, there are more efficient solutions with plain SQL. Looping is a measure of last resort, when you can do things in one scan where you would need multiple scans in pure SQL.

Comment: Also note that if you want to return the table type you can just say something like `CREATE FUNCTION footest() RETURNS SETOF foo LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS $$...`

Comment: Why then we at all have the feature of "composite types" if we can create tables instead, without restrictions applied to composite types (no constraints, etc)? The only meaningful way of using composite types I see is returning a couple (or several) parameters from a function instead of creating a whole table for that.