# `RETURN NEXT` vs `RETURN RECORD` in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql, set-returning-functions, record

What is the difference between `RETURN NEXT` and `RETURN RECORD` in PL/pgSQL? I find the manual quite confusing in explaining what `RETURN RECORD` actually does. What is a `RECORD` type?

Answer (score 4):

While `RETURN NEXT` is valid plpgsql syntax, <strike>`RETURN RECORD`</strike> is non-existent as such. It corresponds to how you declare the return type in the function header. Read the manual about how to [return from a function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING).

In a function declaring `RETURNS int` you can:

```
RETURN 1;
```

For `RETURNS SETOF int` you can:

```
RETURN NEXT 1;
```

If you declare `OUT` parameters, you can just:

```
RETURN;
-- or do nothing: OUT params are returned at the end of the function anyway
```

Or if you combine `OUT` parameters with `RETURNS SETOF record` - effectively the same as `RETURNS TABLE (...)`:

```
RETURN NEXT;
```

The current state of all `OUT` parameters is returned as next row.

Finally, [to return a whole set of rows at once](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#AEN56293):

```
RETURN QUERY ...
```

**`record`** is a *special data type*. It's meaning depends on where you use it. Like I posted in my answer to your previous question:

- [Declare variable of table type in PL/pgSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35721/declare-variable-of-table-type-in-pl-pgsql/35722#35722)

[The manual about the `record` type in PL/pgSQL.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-RECORDS)

Answer (score 0):

#### A [RETURN NEXT statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING-RETURN-NEXT):

- can append zero or more rows to the function's result set one by one and the rows can be modified one by one.
- cannot exit a function while a [RETURN statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING-RETURN) can.
- can work only in a PL/pgSQL function.
- can work only with `SETOF <sometype>` or `TABLE()` in a `RETURNS` clause otherwise there are [the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17570450/error-cannot-use-return-next-in-a-non-setof-function#77975932) and [the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27968966/return-cannot-have-a-parameter-in-function-returning-set-use-return-next-at-or).

*[The doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING-RETURN-NEXT) explains `RETURN NEXT` statement in detail.

#### A [RETURN QUERY statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING-RETURN-NEXT):

- can append zero or more rows to the function's result set at once and the rows cannot be modified.
- cannot exit a function while a [RETURN statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING-RETURN) can.
- can be used with [SELECT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html) or [VALUES](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-values.html) statement.
- can be used with [INSERT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html), [UPDATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html) or [DELETE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-delete.html) statement with [RETURNING clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/dml-returning.html).
- can be used with [EXECUTE statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-execute.html) to be dynamic.
- can work only in a PL/pgSQL function.
- can work only with `SETOF <sometype>` or `TABLE()` in a `RETURNS` clause otherwise there are [the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17570450/error-cannot-use-return-next-in-a-non-setof-function#77975932) and [the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27968966/return-cannot-have-a-parameter-in-function-returning-set-use-return-next-at-or).

*[The doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING-RETURN-NEXT) explains `RETURN QUERY` statement in detail.