# Return both one value and one column from pl/pgsql function

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, plpgsql, record

I wish my pl/pgsql function to go fetch and return two informations in my database in a single connection:

- one vector containing data whose type is unknown at call time (an array)
- one string value containing information as how to interpret this data

Here is an illustration of the function architecture:
What should I use as a return type / return value / return instruction so both these informations are returned?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.retrieve_vector(
    vname bigint)  -- the vector name: actually a column name
    RETURNS RECORD -- * * * is that the return type I need?  * * *
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    VOLATILE
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    info text; -- data interpretation information
BEGIN

-- Retrieve data information from, say, the such-information table
SELECT info FROM public."InfoTable"
    WHERE name = vname
    INTO info; -- (this is actually a more complicated process)

-- Retrieve the vector and return both
RETURN info,
      (SELECT vname FROM public."Vectors"); -- (this is also more complicated)
-- * * * but RETURN a, b; is not possible like this, right? How to do? * * *

END
$BODY$;
```

As dummy instances, I expect this function to return something like `retrieve_vector('temperatures') -> ['old thermometer', [0, 1, 5, -3]]` or `retrieve_vector('words') -> ['small words only', ['at', 'the', 'and', 'or']]`.
(To those who might ask: in reality this is about meta-programming, so the "info" is actually refined *type* information.)

In such a situation, I think that:

- it is legitimate that this function returns two values
- it is legitimate that the vector type is unknown at call time
- it is legitimate that the first value is scalar (single value) and the other is a vector (a column)
- it is legitimate wanting to connect the database only once

Is it possible defining a function with such a flexible signature?
How would I do this?

Comment: postgres needs to know the type at call time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but `RETURN a, b;` is not possible like this, right? How to do?

Right, not like this. But ***this*** is possible:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.retrieve_vector(
   _vname bigint
 , OUT _info text       -- "data interpretation information"
 , OUT _arr  text[]     -- "vector"
   )
  RETURNS record AS     -- that is the return type you need
$func$
BEGIN
   -- Retrieve data information
   SELECT info
   FROM   public."InfoTable"
   WHERE  name = _vname
   INTO   _info;        -- actually a more complicated process

   -- Retrieve "vector"
   SELECT vname         -- you may need explicit casting to text[] ...
   FROM   public."Vectors"
   INTO   _arr;         -- also actually more complicated

   -- RETURN;           -- optional
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Don't quote the language name `plpgsql`.

Assuming you want to return a **single row**. For returning 0-n rows (a *set*) you would use `RETURNS TABLE(_info text,_arr text[])` in combination with `RETURN NEXT` or `RETURN QUERY` or similar. See:

- [Difference between return next and return record](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35746/difference-between-return-next-and-return-record/35750#35750)

The term "vector" in your question does not help to clarify which actual data types we are dealing with. You also mention "array". Any Postgres array can be cast to `text[]`, so I use *that* type as common denominator. PL/pgSQL `SELECT INTO` coerces compatible types into the target data typesd automatically. Else you may need to add an explicit cast like `source_array_column::text[]`. Not enough info in your question to narrow this down.

You asserted that:

> type is unknown at call time

Else you might be able to work with a polymorphic array type as well. See:

- [Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557)

Comment: Okay, so the idea is to use `text[]` as a fixed return type, then interpret the returned data based on `_info` on the caller side. This makes sense if postgres really needs to know the return type at call time. And it only costs one extra cast `::text[]` on each call. Thank you :)