# Use composite type to create new table

Tags: postgresql, database-design, ddl, composite-types

In ORDBMS databases I have seen that complex types can be used:

```
create type name as( ...)
```

And I can references those types when creating a new table, like:

```
create table example (row_name ref(name))
```

How can I achieve the same in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use a **typed table**:

```
CREATE TYPE mytype AS (some_id int, some_col text);

CREATE TABLE example OF mytype (PRIMARY KEY (some_id));
```

I added a PK constraint (which you did not ask for).

The syntax is documented as second variant [in the manual for `CREATE TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html), which also explains further down:

> `OF` ***type_name***
>
> Creates a typed table, which takes its structure from the specified composite type (name optionally schema-qualified). A typed
> table is tied to its type; for example the table will be dropped if
> the type is dropped (with `DROP TYPE ... CASCADE`).
>
> When a typed table is created, then the data types of the columns are determined by the underlying composite type and are not specified
> by the `CREATE TABLE` command. But the `CREATE TABLE` command can add
> defaults and constraints to the table and can specify storage
> parameters.

There is also a code example at the end of the [examples section.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-EXAMPLES)

But I have never used that myself. I prefer to have a template table and copy the structure with `CREATE TABLE tbl1 (LIKE template)`, leaving no ties to the template.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if you want to create a table with a given composite type (as Erwin describes) or one *containing* a composite type.

If the latter, it's almost the same.

```
create type typename as( ...)
```

then

```
create table example (
   row_name typename
)
```

Typically you'd have more columns, like:

```
create table example (
   id serial primary key,
   some_composite typename,
   parent_id integer not null references parenttable(id),
   .... more columns ...
)
```

Comment: That's another way to read the question. `row_name` was my clue to assume a typed table ...

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I think you're quite likely right. I don't know what `ref(x)` means and didn't find it in a 30s search. I just thought it was worth explaining in case the user _did_ mean use of a composite type as a field.

Comment: It's worth explaining in any case. If this user didn't mean it the next one finding this question might.