# Index not used with = ANY() but used with IN

Tags: postgresql, index, optimization, postgresql-9.4, execution-plan

Table `t` has two indexes:

```
create table t (a int, b int);
create type int_pair as (a int, b int);
create index t_row_idx on t (((a,b)::int_pair));
create index t_a_b_idx on t (a,b);

insert into t (a,b)
select i, i
from generate_series(1, 100000) g(i)
;
```

No index is used with the `ANY` operator:

```
explain analyze
select *
from t
where (a,b) = any(array[(1,1),(1,2)])
;
                                            QUERY PLAN                                             
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on t  (cost=0.00..1693.00 rows=1000 width=8) (actual time=0.042..126.789 rows=1 loops=1)
   Filter: (ROW(a, b) = ANY (ARRAY[ROW(1, 1), ROW(1, 2)]))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 99999
 Planning time: 0.122 ms
 Execution time: 126.836 ms
```

But one of them is used with the `IN` operator:

```
explain analyze
select *
from t
where (a,b) in ((1,1),(1,2))
;
                                                    QUERY PLAN                                                    
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Only Scan using t_a_b_idx on t  (cost=0.29..8.32 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.028..0.029 rows=1 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (a = 1)
   Filter: ((b = 1) OR (b = 2))
   Heap Fetches: 1
 Planning time: 0.161 ms
 Execution time: 0.066 ms
```

It uses the record index if the record is cast to the correct type:

```
explain analyze
select *
from t
where (a,b)::int_pair = any(array[row(1,1),row(1,2)])
;
                                                  QUERY PLAN                                                  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using t_row_idx on t  (cost=0.42..12.87 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=0.106..0.126 rows=1 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (ROW(a, b)::int_pair = ANY (ARRAY[ROW(1, 1), ROW(1, 2)]))
 Planning time: 0.208 ms
 Execution time: 0.203 ms
```

Why doesn't the planner use the non record index for the `ANY` operator as it uses it for the `IN` operator?

Comment: This interesting question emerged from a related discussion on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34601242/939860

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Internally, there are **two separate forms** of `IN`, and also two separate forms of the `ANY` construct.

One of each, taking a ***set***, is equivalent to the other and `expr IN (<set>)` also leads to the same query plan as `expr = ANY(<set>)` that can use a plain index. Details:

- [IN vs ANY operator in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34627688/939860)

Consequently, the following two queries are equivalent and both can use the plain index `t_a_b_idx` (which can also be the **solution** if you are trying to get your query to use the index):

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE (a,b) = ANY(VALUES (1,1),(1,2));
```

Or:

```
...
WHERE (a,b) IN (VALUES (1,1),(1,2));
```

Identical for both:

> ```
>                                                         QUERY PLAN
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>  Nested Loop  (cost=0.33..16.71 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.101..0.101 rows=0 loops=1)
>    ->  Unique  (cost=0.04..0.05 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=0.068..0.070 rows=2 loops=1)
>          ->  Sort  (cost=0.04..0.04 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=0.067..0.068 rows=2 loops=1)
>                Sort Key: "*VALUES*".column1, "*VALUES*".column2
>                Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
>                ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..0.03 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=2 loops=1)
>    ->  Index Only Scan using t_plain_idx on t  (cost=0.29..8.32 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=0 loops=2)
>          Index Cond: ((a = "*VALUES*".column1) AND (b = "*VALUES*".column2))
>          Heap Fetches: 0
>  Planning time: 4.080 ms
>  Execution time: 0.202 ms
> ```

**However**, this cannot easily be passed to a function, since there are no "table variables" in Postgres. Which leads to the problem that started this topic:

- [Pass multiple sets or arrays of values to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34601242/939860)

There are various workarounds for that problem. One being the alternative answer I added there. Some others:

- [Insert values from a record variable into a table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52826/insert-values-from-a-record-variable-into-a-table/52904#52904)
- [Declare variable of table type in PL/pgSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35721/declare-variable-of-table-type-in-pl-pgsql/35722#35722)

---

The second form of each is different: `ANY` takes an actual ***array***, while `IN` takes a comma separated ***list of values***.

This has different consequences for **typing** the input. As we can see in the `EXPLAIN` output of the question, this form:

```
WHERE (a,b) = ANY(ARRAY[(1,1),(1,2)]);
```

is seen as shorthand for:

```
ROW(a, b) = ANY (ARRAY[ROW(1, 1), ROW(1, 2)])
```

And actual ROW values are compared. Postgres is not currently smart enough to see that the index on the composite type `t_row_idx` is applicable. Nor does it realize that the simple index `t_a_b_idx` should be applicable as well.

An explicit cast helps to overcome this lack of smarts:

```
WHERE (a,b)::int_pair = ANY(ARRAY[(1,1),(1,2)]::int_pair[]);
```

Casting the right operand (`::int_pair[]`) is optional (though preferable for performance and to avoid ambiguities). Once the left operand has a well-known type, the right operand is coerced from "anonymous record" to a matching type. Only then, the operator is defined unambiguously. And Postgres picks applicable indexes based on the *operator* and the *left* operand. For many operators that define a `COMMUTATOR`, the query planner can flip operands to bring the indexed expression to the left. But that's not possible with the `ANY` construct.

Related:

- [Is there a way to usefully index a text column containing regex patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34505673/939860)

  ```
    WHERE (a,b) IN ((1,1),(1,2));
  ```

.. values are taken as *elements* and Postgres is able to compare individual integer values as we can see in the `EXPLAIN` output once more:

> ```
> Filter: ((b = 1) OR (b = 2))
> ```

Hence Postgres finds that the simple index `t_a_b_idx` can be used.

---

Consequently, there would be another **solution for the particular case in the example**: since the custom composite type `int_pair` in the example happens to be equivalent to the row type of the table `t` itself, we could simplify:

```
CREATE INDEX t_row_idx2 ON t ((t.*));
```

Shorter, equivalent syntax:

```
CREATE INDEX t_row_idx2 ON t ((t));
```

But the first variant is safer. The second variant would resolve to the column if a column of the same name should exist.

Then this query would use the index without any more explicit casting:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT *
FROM   t
WHERE  t = ANY(ARRAY[(1,1),(1,2)]);
```

> ```
>                                                       QUERY PLAN
> -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>  Bitmap Heap Scan on t  (cost=40.59..496.08 rows=1000 width=8) (actual time=0.19
> 1..0.191 rows=0 loops=1)
>    Recheck Cond: (t.* = ANY (ARRAY[ROW(1, 1), ROW(1, 2)]))
>    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on t_row_idx2  (cost=0.00..40.34 rows=1000 width=0) (actual time=0.188..0.188 rows=0 loops=1)
>          Index Cond: (t.* = ANY (ARRAY[ROW(1, 1), ROW(1, 2)]))
>  Planning time: 2.575 ms
>  Execution time: 0.267 ms
> ```

But typical use cases won't be able to utilize the implicitly existing type of the table row.

Comment: A minor addition: while a short `IN(...)` list may be translated (by the planner) into an `... OR ...` expression in the above case, it is usually just translated into `ANY('{...}')`, that is, using an array.  So, in most cases, `IN` with a list of values and `ANY` with an array are the same thing.

Comment: @dezso: For most simple cases, yes. The question demonstrates a case where `IN(...)` *cannot*  be translated to `= ANY('{...}')`.