# Testing if an element in a PostgreSQL array?

Tags: postgresql, array

Is there an operator in PostgreSQL to test whether an element is in an array?

Currently, I'm doing such tests in a slightly complex way by first constructing a singleton array for the element and then using the [`<@` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-array.html) between arrays.

```
SELECT ARRAY[1] <@ ARRAY[1,2,3];
```

( `SELECT 1 <@ ARRAY[1,2,3];` does not work).

Is there a more succinct/clear way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the element to check for is **never `NULL`**, your original method

```
SELECT ARRAY[1] <@ ARRAY[1,2,3];
```

delivers superior performance in the presence of a matching **index** for the *array* column (`int[]` in your example). See:

- [Can PostgreSQL index array columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4058731/939860)

If it's all about **`integer`** arrays, consider the additional module `intarray` for superior performance.

- [How to create an index for elements of an array in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10868144/939860)

If your column actually is the array *element* in the expression (plain `integer` in your example), consider:

- [Index not used with = ANY() but used with IN](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/125413/index-not-used-with-any-but-used-with-in/125500#125500)

OTOH, if `NULL` values can be involved on either side of the expression and you don't want `NULL` for `NULL` input, rather treat `NULL` like any other element, then use [**`array_position()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) (Postgres 9.5 or later) like this:

```
SELECT array_position(ARRAY[1,2,3], 1) IS NOT NULL;
SELECT array_position(ARRAY[1,2,NULL,3], NULL) IS NOT NULL;
```

Related:

- [Check if NULL exists in Postgres array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34848472/939860)

For tests without index support and no `NULL` values involved (or if you are happy with `NULL` on `NULL` input) and performance is not important, use the  generic `ANY` construct [like Vérace demonstrates](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/207244/3684).

Comment: Why does `SELECT ARRAY_POSITION(ARRAY[1,2,3], '2')` return 2? `2` <> 2 as far as I know..

Comment: @RTD: I don't follow. `ARRAY[1,2,3]` defaults to `int[]`, the untyped (!) literal `'2'` is coerced to the matching type `int`. The value is found at position *2*. What would you expect it to return?

Comment: I expected it to return NULL since '2' is not in the ARRAY; 2 is. I didn't expect '2' to be coerced to int, as it is written as '2', yet you say it is untyped..

Comment: @RTD Array and element type must match, or you get an error msg for the type mismatch, rather than `null`.

Comment: Fair enough. I wasn't aware of the implicit coercion bit. I expected Postgres not to coerce char '2' to int 2. Good to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `ANY` construct!

To answer your question, I did the following:

Created a table:

```
CREATE TABLE arr_test
(
  my_name VARCHAR(15),
  my_int_array INTEGER []
);
```

Added a couple of sample records:

```
INSERT INTO arr_test VALUES ('fred', '{1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9}');
INSERT INTO arr_test VALUES ('bill', '{34, 45, 56, 67}');
```

Ran my query:

```
SELECT * FROM arr_test
WHERE 34 = ANY (my_int_array);

Result:
my_name     my_int_array
   bill    {34,45,56,67}
```

The fiddle is available [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=4f088822993f5a15a46339706849ac9b). I hope this answers your question - if not, please let me know!

Comment: Good to know. Why does `SELECT '2' = ANY(ARRAY[1,2,3])` return `true`? It is treating '2' as 2.. which is wrong IMO. Using PG11.