# Loop through key/value pairs of a jsonb object in postgresql function

Tags: postgresql, json, plpgsql

I am trying to create a function in Postgres that can loop through each key/value pair in a given `jsonb` object.

```
create or replace function myFunction
(input jsonb)
returns jsonb as $$
BEGIN

    // foreach(key in input)
    //       do some math operation on its corresponding value

    returns input;

END; $$
```

The argument input is expected to be a jsonb object, such as `{"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}`.

I want to loop through each key/value pair in the object. As you can tell from my comment, I used to write backend code with more general-purpose programming languages like c, java, etc. So I am not good at SQL. I have tried to search online, but they talk about how to loop through `jsonb` array instead of object. So really stuck here.

Comment: What are you trying to do with those values inside the loop? What's wrong with `SELECT jsonb_each_text('{"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}')`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use [`jsonb_each(jsonb)` or `jsonb_each_text(jsonb)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) in a [`FOR` loop](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING) like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function(input jsonb)
  RETURNS jsonb
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS  -- language declaration required
$func$
DECLARE
   _key   text;
   _value text;
BEGIN
    FOR _key, _value IN
       SELECT * FROM jsonb_each_text($1)
    LOOP
       -- do some math operation on its corresponding value
       RAISE NOTICE '%: %', _key, _value;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN input;
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT my_function('{"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}');
```

Related:

- [Declare variable of table type in PL/pgSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35721/declare-variable-of-table-type-in-pl-pgsql/35722#35722)

Note that for many problems where people used to *programming languages like c, java, etc.* would tend to use a loop, there is a superior set-based solution in SQL around the corner. Side-by-side code examples:

- [Postgres FOR LOOP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19147320/939860)
- [Syntax error in a Postgres statement with procedural code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19147758/939860)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Mind if I ask what is the set-based solution? @Erwin Brandstetter

Comment: @JaneL: I added side-by-side code examples above to clarify. And I fixed the sneaky bug in my demo that sparked https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/231068/3684

Comment: Excellent example. What `$1` refers to?

Comment: @Jeb50: Function parameters can be referred to by name (if one is given) or by ordinal position with `$n`notation. So `$1` refers to the first function parameter.