# Surprising results from assigning multiple variables in FOR loop

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, set-returning-functions

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function(input jsonb)
  RETURNS jsonb
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS  -- language declaration required
$func$
DECLARE
   _key   text;
   _value text;
BEGIN
    FOR _key, _value IN
      SELECT jsonb_each_text($1)
    LOOP
        -- do some math operation on its corresponding value
        RAISE NOTICE '%: %', _key, _value;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN input;
END
$func$;
```

For the function, if I call:

```
my_function('{"a":1, "b":2}');
```

It will raise notice that looks like (a, 1), (b, 2) in the message box.

However, if I change the code:

```
        RAISE NOTICE '%: %', _key, _value;
```

into:

```
        RAISE NOTICE '%', _key;
```

The same results will pop up.

While the code:

```
        RAISE NOTICE '%', _value;
```

would pop up nothing. How did that happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess I am to blame for this confusion.
The code example is from my [answer to your previous question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/231017/3684), which had a subtle bug (now fixed).

#### What was going wrong?

`jsonb_each_text()` is a [set-returning function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html), it returns a set of **rows**. When called with:

```
SELECT * FROM jsonb_each_text('{"a":1, "b":2}')
```

it returns:

```
 key | value 
-----+-------
 a   | 1
 b   | 2
```

But when called like above with:

```
SELECT jsonb_each_text('{"a":1, "b":2}')
```

it returns:

```
 jsonb_each_text 
-----------------
 (a,1)
 (b,2)
```

Each row is returned with a *single* value, a [row value](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS), the text representation of which is as displayed.

Now, the assignment in:

```
  FOR _key, _value IN SELECT jsonb_each_text($1) ...
```

assigns the first value per row to the first variable provided, which is `_key` in the example. The row value is cast to `text` in the assignment. Since there is no second value, `_value` is set to `NULL`. So, the later:

```
 RAISE NOTICE '%: %', _key, _value;
```

outputs the messages:

```
NOTICE:  (a,1): <NULL>
NOTICE:  (b,2): <NULL>
```

Which can be pretty misleading. (But note the dangling `: <NULL>`!)

Change to:

```
FOR _key, _value IN SELECT * FROM jsonb_each_text($1)
```

.. and the mists should clear.